# How to get docstrings from decorated functions in Python with autodoc?

Tags: python, django, python-sphinx, python-decorators, autodoc

There is a officially known problem with `sphinx autodoc` that when your function is decorated, its docstring won't show up in the generated docs.

From the [autodoc home page](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html):

> If you document decorated functions or methods, keep in mind that autodoc retrieves its docstrings by importing the module and inspecting the **doc** attribute of the given function or method. From Python 2.5, functools.wraps() can be used to create well-behaved decorating functions.

So, using the the `functools.wraps()` does work.

```
def decorator_func(say_hello_func):       
    """Docstring for decorator_func"""    
    @wraps(say_hello_func)    
    def wrapper_func(hello_var, world_var):    
        """Docstring for wrapper_func"""    
        return say_hello_func(hello_var, world_var)    
    return wrapper_func


@decorator_func    
def say_hello(hello_var, world_var):    
    """Docstring for say_hello function.

    Args:    
        hello_var (str): hello_var    
        world_var (str): world_var

    Returns:    
        str: concatenation of the strings    
    """    
    print hello_var + " " + world_var
```

producing (with poor formatting pasted)

```
say_hello(hello_var, world_var)

Docstring for say_hello function.

Parameters:

·         hello_var (str) – hello_var

·         world_var (str) – world_var

Returns:

concatenation of the strings

Return type:

str
```

However, there are cases when you have a 3rd party package from which you can take a decorator. However, it is impractical to modify the source of the package adding `functools.wraps()` everywhere in their source code - the work you've done will be gone after the next update of this package, for the very least.

Is there any alternative solution that does not involve modifying the source code of 3rd party packages (e.g. Django) from which you are taking the decorators?

A simple example could look like this. The `save` function won't have its docstring pulled unless you go to the source of django and add the `@wraps` there.

```
from django.db import transaction

@transaction.atomic
def save(self):
    """Docstring to be used"""
    pass
```

Comment: *"However, there are cases when you have a 3rd party package from which you can take a decorator"*. Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates such a case?

Comment: I've added a sample